Failed to solve motion; most likely there are no good keyframes error
I'm getting this error that doesn't let me continue with the cleaning process, i've already searched and everyone says about having less than 8 points, but i'm just starting the cleaning process i have more than even 50 points, so why is this happening?
The weird thing about it is that the first time i press Solve Camera Motion it works correctly, but if i press again with the same changes or i try to clean up and press Solve the error message appears, so it looks like just blender messing with me with random errors with no logic. Has anybody encountered this problem?
This is my tracking with tons of markers (that seems to be less than 8 for Blender)

